# Update with join throws "The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once."

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-merge

I have an UPDATE query with a JOIN that's throwing the following error:

*The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group the source rows.*

Here's my update statement:

```
UPDATE
    Products
SET
    price = pu.ColumnValue
FROM
    Products p
    JOIN #priceupdates pu ON p.sku = pu.sku AND p.idManufacturer = pu.idManufacturer
```

Products joins on #priceupdates by SKU and idManufacturer.

There are no duplicates or NULLs in my #priceupdates table.

**Edit:**

To prove it, I ran the following 2 statements, and they both returned the same amount of records:

```
select sku, idmanufacturer from #priceupdates
select distinct sku, idmanufacturer from #priceupdates
```

**End Edit**

Depending on the data in #priceupdates it does or does not throw the error, but I'm having a hard time finding which data is the source of the problem.

So, besides for having duplicates, what other factors can cause this error?

Any help is appreciated.

**Edit 2:**

Here's test data. I can't give you a repro because as I said I can't find which data is giving me the problem.

```
CREATE TABLE #Products (idProduct INT, SKU VARCHAR(50), idManufacturer INT, Price FLOAT)
INSERT INTO #Products
SELECT '316992', '00015', '123', '0.52'
UNION SELECT '316993', '00037', '123', '0.52'
UNION SELECT '316994', '00039', '123', '0.52'
UNION SELECT '316995', '00115', '123', '0.52'
UNION SELECT '316996', '00137', '123', '0.52' 

CREATE TABLE #PriceUpdates (ProductUpdateID INT, SKU VARCHAR(50), idManufacturer INT, ColumnName VARCHAR(50), ColumnValue VARCHAR(50), idUser INT, BatchID INT)
INSERT INTO #PriceUpdates
SELECT '1837', '00015', '123', 'Price', '0.99', '13', '1929'
UNION SELECT '1838', '00037', '123', 'Price', '0.99', '13', '1929'
UNION SELECT '1839', '00039', '123', 'Price', '0.99', '13', '1929'
UNION SELECT '1840', '00115', '123', 'Price', '0.99', '13', '1929'
UNION SELECT '1841', '00137', '123', 'Price', '0.99', '13', '1929' 

UPDATE
    p
SET
    price = pu.ColumnValue 
FROM
    #Products p
    JOIN #priceupdates pu ON p.sku = pu.sku AND p.idManufacturer = pu.idManufacturer

 DROP TABLE #Products
 DROP TABLE #PriceUpdates
```

**UPDATE!**

I *think* I found the culprit. When I exclude a specific record from the priceupdates table, it works! But I still don't know what's wrong with that record. Where do I go from here? NOTE: when I *only* include that record, the update works as well.

Comment: Short answer is that while it is possible that #priceupdates is unique across all columns it cannot be unique against sku and manufacturer. You have multiple records in #priceupdates for the same sku/manufacturer combination.

Comment: Try aggregating the population of #priceupdates on sku/manufacturer and get the max/min/avg/etc of the columnvalue.

Comment: @Love2Learn See my edit - #priceupdates is unique by sku and idmanufacturer

Comment: When you ran those queries was it failing? You said it is intermittent, was that simply one of the times it was not failing. Can you provide the declaration definition of `#priceupdates`?

Comment: You need to add more context. How about some sample data and a repro?

Comment: I would add a primary key to your temp table. That will give you a new error if you're wrong about the uniqueness. ;) It will also help you identify where the duplicate insert logic is occurring though.

Comment: My columns in #priceupdates are: ProductUpdateID (unique), sku, idManufacturer, ColumnName, ColumnValue, UploadDate, idUser, BatchID. Give me a few, I'll try to come up with test data and a repro.

Comment: I updated my OP with sample data.

Comment: I don't see a MERGE statement in your code. Does the error really call it MERGE when using an UPDATE? Hard to believe. Also, UPDATEs don't have that message at all. The message clearly refers to a MERGE and an ON clause.

Comment: @usr OMG. I knew that all along and it seemed weird to me but you just made me realize where this is coming from - a TRIGGER!!!!!!!!

Comment: Why the downvote? Does my OP not show any research effort? Or is it unclear? Yes, it turned out we were looking in the wrong place - that was part of the question though - finding the *source* of the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My comment turned out to be an answer:

I don't see a `MERGE` statement in your code. Does the error really call it `MERGE` when using an `UPDATE`? Hard to believe. Also, `UPDATEs` don't have that message at all. The message clearly refers to a `MERGE` and an `ON` clause.

The `UPDATE` is not the problem. Look elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you @usr. Thanks to LoveToLearn and AaronBertrand for bearing with me.